# How to deploy VHD image to physical disk?

Tags: windows, virtualization, windows-server-2012-r2, vhd

I'm trying to take a VHD containing a generalized Windows install from azure and deploy the image to a physical disk on one of our servers.  What's the best way to go about doing this?  Can I use ImageX to handle this sort of scenario?  I know that it can handle WIM images, but not too sure about VHD.  I've tried to use Vhd2disk but to no avail as it didn't see any volumes on the VHD, which there must be because I can mount and browse the VHD just fine.

Comment: You need to convert the VHD into a RAW format first. Vboxmanage that comes with virtualbox has that capability.Then you can use a regular imaging tool such as clonezilla or dd.

Answer (score 1):

Native VHD Boot may be one option.  (Should only be used in test environments, not production).

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/516.how-to-boot-from-a-vhd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try [vhd2disk](http://forum.sysinternals.com/vhd2disk_topic27311.html) by Mark Russinovich, one of the sysinternals guys.

Comment: the Link is Dead. any chance anyone knows updated link?